# How do I change the center of view in Sword of the Stars in tactical (real-time combat) mode?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars

Several years ago when I played this game on Windows XP there was a simple way to do this, but I don't recall exactly how.  I think just double-left-click on the desired center-point did the trick.  (That works during in strategic mode.)  I'm now playing this great classic on Windows 7.  Everything seems to work fine, except for this one thing, and I wondering if maybe I'm overlooking something.

The problem is that in tactical mode the center-point defaults to the first ship in the formation.  This would be fine, but unfortunately this is also the first ship that usually gets destroyed.  So, it becomes a real pain to change the view around and direct combat actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the middle mouse button, or F key.